# How to use subselect in a where clause of a JasperReport dataset definition?

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I try to define a dataset in a JasperSoft report (JasperSoft Studio V 5.6) that uses a subselect with a parameter like this:

```
SELECT id, value FROM foo WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM bar WHERE user=$P{USER_PARAM})
```

The *SELECT* of the subselect statement is commented with the error message `'no viable alternative at input 'select''`.

[image: Dataset and Query Dialog Screenshot]

The SQL statement is executable using simple database tools, so there must be something special in der JasperReports syntax.

I am grateful for any information how to implement my use case in JasperSoft. If the subselect is not supported, what is the recommended way to define the query?

Comment: Have you tried using **$P!{USER_PARAM}** (i.e. using the variant with an exclamation mark)?

Comment: @FrVaBe The subselect is supported by *JasperReports*

Comment: **$P!** makes no difference. The problem is the nested __SELECT__ (see my screenshot without parameter usage). I am convinced that JasperReports supports a subselect but I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: @FrVaBe Did you try to ignore the GUI warning and test the report? Did you try to use *iReport*?

Answer (score -1):

When using subselect statement in Jaspersoft Studio, it will through the error you have mentioned. But if you ignore the error and Click "Read Fields", it reads your column fields and when you use it in the report the result is achieved.

I have tested this and it works!!!